# Intercept Command-Quit in Mac App?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks

I would like to make an app for Mac (Mavericks) that does not handle the command-quit option.

I found the following solution but it must be out of date because I get an error:

```
    CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap,
                                          kCGHeadInsertEventTap,
                                          kCGEventTapOptionDefault,
                                          CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown),
                                          &KeyDownCallback,
                                          NULL);

CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
CFRelease(runLoopSource);
CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);
```

Another other ways? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have your application delegate implement the [`applicationShouldTerminate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW4) method:

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    // work out whether to actually quit or not
    BOOL shouldQuit = /* insert logic here */;
    if (shouldQuit)
        return NSTerminateNow;
    else
        return NSTerminateCancel;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, didn't think of doing it that way. Thanks a lot.