# How to add Command-Q logic in Cocoa with Swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift, xcode6

I want to add some logic in my Cocoa app when an user puts Command-Q to try to quit the app, but how can I add it in Swift?

What I want to do is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377811/intercept-command-quit-in-mac-app), but this is on Objective-C and when I tried to port it to my Swift app, it doesn't succeed since it looks like `applicationShouldTerminate` is no longer available in Swift, given that it doesn't react to the completion of the method in my Xcode.

Also, when I tried to write `NSTerminateNow` like the one written on the post above, I got an unresolved error, so `NSTerminateNow` is also gone in Swift and Xcode 6.

So if I want to add some logic after an user puts Command-Q in my Swift and Cocoa app, how can I implement it in Xcode 6? Should I avoid using `applicationShouldTerminate` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still there, it's just hiding. If you command click on NSApplicationDelegate in your app delegate's declaration, you can see all the methods it implements, including:

```
func applicationShouldTerminate(sender: NSApplication!) -> NSApplicationTerminateReply {
    // stuff and return stuff    
}
```

It seems that (hopefully just for now) optional methods declared in protocols, aren't suggested by autocomplete.

Comment: Thanks for the info on checking out all method declarations! And it was my mistake to define `NSTerminateNow` as it is - it should be `.TerminateNow` as suggested by Martin R, which caused the second issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The same method works in Swift without problems:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    // ...

    func applicationShouldTerminate(sender: NSApplication!) -> NSApplicationTerminateReply {
        let shouldTerminate = ... // Should I stay or should I go?
        return shouldTerminate ? .TerminateNow : .TerminateCancel
    }

}
```

Comment: method does not call when I hit on command Q.